# Change FlatButton icon size

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm building a `react` `material-ui` virtual (on-screen) keyboard. And I'm having hard time implementing key size future. I'm using `FlatButtton` I figured a way to change `label`'s size when i use label to display symbol key but I haven't found a way to change `icon`'s size when using `icon` and `SvgIcon`. I have tried with `label` and `labelStyle` but dose not look stylish as with text `label`.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is how I change `label`'s size:

```
let theme: MuiTheme = getMuiTheme();
theme.button.height += 10;
theme.button.minWidth += 10;
theme.flatButton.fontSize += 10;

return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
        <div>
             <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
              <Keyboard
                  textField={textField}
                  open={this.state.open}
                  onRequestClose={this._onRequestClose}
                  onInput={this._onInput}
                  layout={[AlphaNumericKeyboard]}
               />
        </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

The code is just for developing, my idea when I'm done is to remove `link` and `div` and replace `getMuiTheme()` with `this.context.muiTheme` and `+= 10` with a `= this.props.keySize`.

This is the code which I use to change `icon`'s size:

`React.cloneElement(icon, {style: {width: 34, height: 34}});`

This works when I `render` just the `icon` but when I `render` using `<FlatButton icon={React.cloneElement(icon, {style: {width: 34, height: 34}})} />;`

It's always with size 24x24. I've tried with `theme.button.iconButtonSize += 10;` but still no results.

I've started browsing `material-ui`'s source code but still haven't found a way to change it's size.

This is the last think I've tried since I found that FlatButton dose change `margin` and `padding` and thought space is not enough but there is still total of 42x42 space empty and this dose not help ...

```
const noStyl: React.CSSProperties = {
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0
};
keyboardKey = <FlatButton icon={React.cloneElement(icon, {style: {width: 34, height: 34}})} labelStyle={noStyl} />;
```

So is there a way to change `icon`'s size when using a `FlatButton` ?

Comment: If you are using svg-icons, then probably `viewBox` property is what you want. Take a look at available svg-icons properties at the bottom of the page - http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/svg-icon

Comment: ```viewBox``` can only decrease size (I need increased size).```viewBox```  just says how icon should be placed and sized inside the svg element. I wan't change that element size.

Comment: It is possible to increase size of the icon via `viewBox`. It accepts four values: `x1 y1 x2 y2`, where (x1, y1) represents top left corner and (x2, y2) represents bottom right corner. Svg icon itself will be stretched between these coordinates. By default the value is `0 0 24 24`, to increase icon size you can use for example `0 0 36 36`.

Comment: Note: `viewBox` might be a bit tricky, if parent size is different from `viewBox` size. Here you can find a good explanation of how `viewBox` works - https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/#viewbox-syntax.

Comment: Or have I misunderstood you? Do you need to change size of icon element, which holds svg icon, but not a size of svg icon?

Comment: The problem of  changing just a ```viewBox``` is that it won't change svg's size I've tried. The problem is that ```FlatButton``` and ```RaisedButton``` just overwrites  ```style prop``` I'm going to close this question it's ```material-ui``` problem I made an Issue if no one do any thing in the next 2/3 days I will create Pull request and just add ```IconStyle``` following ```IconButton``` ...

Answer (score 0):

As of `v0.15.2` `icon` `style` `prop` is been overwritten (there is no way to style `icon` from `FlatButton`/`RiasedButton`.

Comment: As of `v0.15.3` `icon` `style`  `prop` is beeing merged.with default styles.